# Flutter getting unknown error from firebase authentication service

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have released my first app to google play and opened it for several test users.
I am using Firebase Authentication service for managing users.

When my test users try to signup (by email and password), they get an unknown error.
Are there any special changes I need to do before releasing my app?
My functionality is quite simple so I really don't know why they get an error.

Thank you in advance.

Error:

```
"[firebase_auth/unknown] There was an error while initializing the connection to the GoogleApi: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isAtLeastR()Z in class La/d/g/a; or its super classes (declaration of 'a.d.g.a' appears in /data/app/com.omertab.appname--WeJcqqlq_1NPgpgJc96JQ==/base.apk)"
```

Instance:

```
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

My functionality:

```
MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  _showSpinner = true;
                  try {
                    final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
                    if (newUser != null) {
                      await _fireStore.collection('users').add({
                        'email': email,
                        'uId': _auth.currentUser.uid
                      });
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomePage.screenId);
                      _showSpinner = false;
                    }
                  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                    _showSpinner = false;
                    print(e.code);
                    if(e.code == "invalid-email") {
                      print("INVALID EMAIL");
                      setState(() {
                        signupError = "Invalid mail";
                      });
                    } else if(e.code == "invalid-password") {
                      print("INVALID PASS");
                      setState(() {
                        signupError = "Invalid password";
                      });
                    } else if(e.code == "weak-password") {
                      setState(() {
                        signupError = "Please choose a stronger password";
                      });
                    } else if(e.code == "unknown") {
                      setState(() {
                        signupError = "Unknown error occurred";
                      });
                    }
                  }
                },
                minWidth: 200.0,
                height: 42.0,
                child: Text(
                  'Signup',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
```

Comment: Share with us the **error** you are getting

Comment: Sorry.error: "[firebase_auth/unknown] There was an error while initializing the connection to the GoogleApi: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isAtLeastR()Z in class La/d/g/a; or its super classes (declaration of 'a.d.g.a' appears in /data/app/com.omertab.appname--WeJcqqlq_1NPgpgJc96JQ==/base.apk)"

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.
I implemented

implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0"){ force = true }

to build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Not the problem described, but it might help someone. I was getting a different error:

```
[firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND ]
```

I've solved it by activating the authentication service in the Firebase console.